# Client Side Asynchronous Call in Meteor?

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, client-side

I have a Meteor client-side asynchronous call that I can't seem to get a return value from. I know I can't use futures on the client-side, so I'm stuck.

And since the Meteor.call() is from the client-side, it has to be asynchronous. It looks like this:

`Meteor.call('DirList', path, function(error, result) {
console.log(result);
    });`

The console.log() works fine, but how do I get the result back into the surrounding function?

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the result in a `Session` variable and then do the logic with the variable inside a `Deps.autorun` context. Like:

```
Meteor.call('DirList', path, function(error, result) { Session.set('result', result); });
Deps.autorun(function (c) {
  var result = Session.get('result');
  if (!result) return;
  c.stop();
  alert(result);
});
```

Comment: @gabrielpuglises  Yes, indeed, that does work. Thank you! It feels a little weird to be using session variables (meant for saving state) in that way. Would you say that's the Meteor "best practice" or "official" way to handle client-side asynchronous return variables?

Comment: Yes, that's the common way to do that and if you continue to use Meteor you will see it's more natural than you think. Just take care for not using it too much. Your code will become unreadable if you do that.